# How to enable developer mode in android phone YU yureka?

Tags: android, android-4.4-kitkat, cyanogenmod

I could enable developer mode in my Yureka(Cyanogenmode 11) phone. But also it is not asking permission to connect to my computer and my computer only showing ?????????? in devices list. What should I do now ?

Comment: What's your computer? Windows or Linux?

Comment: http://www.androidtip.info/enable-developer-options-turn-usb-debugging-mode-on-in-yu-yureka.html

Comment: @StephanBranczyk Linux, Ubuntu

Comment: I think it's same on all mobiles. Go to setting > about phone > click 3-4 times in Build number. Tell me if this help :)

Comment: @Ajeet I could enable developer options

Comment: Ok, have you installed ADB driver for your phone ?

Comment: I am using Linux based system. Do I need to install driver ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got reason why eclipse showing my phone as unknown device.
My phones USB computer connection was Media device (MTP). I just unchecked media device connection. And now my device is listing properly in eclipse.

Comment: Who r u? You belongs to MACET...

Comment: @BlueGreen What is MACET?